# getting only the most recent post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, users and posts. I'm trying to write a single query that finds the latest post by a user, but I'm having trouble. Here's what I have so far.

`select a.username, b.last_post from logins as a join (select login_id, entry as last_post from posts) as b where a.id = b.login_id`

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| username  | last_post           |
+-----------+---------------------+
| something | 2013-10-08 22:12:00 |
| other     | 2013-10-08 22:13:00 |
| test      | 2013-10-08 22:13:03 |
| test      | 2013-10-08 22:14:20 |
| hello     | 2013-10-08 22:12:53 |
| hello     | 2013-10-08 22:12:56 |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

So right now `last_post` is simply the timestamp of the post it's pulling. How do I get a table that displays *ONLY* the last post from these users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only need two column, you can directly use `MAX()`

```
SELECT a.username, 
       MAX(b.entry) last_post 
FROM   logins a 
       INNER JOIN posts b 
         ON a.id = b.login_id
GROUP  BY a.username
```

otherwise, if you want to show all columns in all table, you can have subquery which separately gets the latest `entry` for every `login_id`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    logins a 
        INNER JOIN posts b 
            ON a.id = b.login_id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  login_id, MAX(entry) entry
            FROM    posts
            GROUP   BY login_id
        ) c ON  b.login_id = c.login_id AND
                b.entry = c.entry
```

Comment: thank you! can you explain the use of `group by` in the first query but not in the second? i used the second one by the way.

Comment: it simply group the record by `username` and for every user, it gets the latest `entry` using `MAX()`